# Got a string (data) but parser requires a pathlike object with extension

Tags: python, file, memory

I am trying to load a variable [str] into a function that requires a FilePath.
This method checks whether the filename has the correct suffix.
This works fine if I have a local file, but it doesn't if I only have the contents and I cannot write to a local file in the proces.

Question:
Is there a way to write my str to (for example) a buffer (StringIO) including an extension so I can pass it as a FilePath directing to the buffer?

See below:

```
def can_parse(self, filename: FilePath) -> bool:
    """Verifies if a file or directory can be parsed with this instance.

    :param filename: File path to the file or directory to parse.
    :type filename: FilePath
    :return: True if it can be parsed, False otherwise.
    :rtype: bool
    """
    if not filename:
        return False

    return (filename.suffix == "" and filename.name in self.suffix_list) or (
        filename.suffix in self.suffix_list
    )
```

Comment: Write the data to a temporary file, then pass the filename to the function.

Comment: I think you can use `NamedTemporaryFile` this is included in `tempfile`. This will generate file on temporary base where you can access its directory and file name after some time that file will be automatically deleted. If you want I can show you the example.